# asp.net 4.5 bundlling: Is that correct to have separated bundles for masterpage and page?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.5

It is a very simple plan: 
We write styles and scripts for Master Page contents and include references in MasterPage.Master file and for each wrapped asp.net Web Forms we have separated .css and .js files those be referenced in own pages.

What is correct way to bundle files in this situation?

1. we bundle all files in one virtual path. so we have unnecessary bundled files in all pages.
2. we create one bundles for master and for each page we add new bundle. in my opinion this approach is similar to hard-coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is about how you want group your CSS and JS files, which depends on the domain of the project. For example in a newspaper project I worked on we did bundling this way: made groups of bundles for article pages, widget pages which all used  the same master page.

For master page you register a bundle which contains necessary libraries which are bound to be used on all pages, such as jQuery, bootstrap, some common javascript files used across all pages in project.

For javascript, Master page will look like this:

```
<script src='@Scripts.Url("~/bundles/js/common")' async> </script>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BottomScripts" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Then on pages which use the layout of Master Page you fill the content placeholder with another bundle extending the common bundle.

For Article pages:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="BottomScripts" runat="server">
  <script src='@Scripts.Url("~/bundles/js/articlePage")' async> </script>
</asp:Content>
```

So `'~/bundles/js/articlePage'` has a bunch of js files which are used on all article pages. The article page will render both common and specific javascript.

In similar way, `'~/bundles/js/sectionPage'` will have a different set of scripts.

Hope this helps

Comment: Using "/" for classifying and creating virtual sub-paths is an interesting idea. It appears this method is structural. Now, I think about naming rules! Do you agree with: name of page = name of virtual sub-path?

Comment: Well, it depends on the total number of pages of the website you have. Some pages, as I mentioned, might need to be grouped as they use the same js-s. E.g you have several similar pages: articles, slideshows, quizzes, all they use basically the same js, so you can use the same virtual path for them, like '~/bundles/js/articles'.